# Source not found for a file that I have open

Tags: java, eclipse

For some reason, when I'm debugging a particular class that I'm editing, Eclipse opens a new tab for that class, saying "Source not found." Meanwhile, methods on the call stack from other classes work fine. Furthermore, when I go back to the correct tab with my source, I can mouseover variables and see their values. But every time I step, it pops over to the Source not found tab. What should I be trying out?

[image: Source not found screenshot]

**Edit** Doh! I just needed to add that project to the source lookup path. It was a new project that wasn't in the source lookup path (while its dependency project was).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this is usually that the classpath used to launch the debug session is not including the Project itself (and thus not including the Project's source). Most likely it is including the generated .class files of the Project explicitly, which is almost never what you want.

1. Check the classpath settings of the Launch Configuration you're using to start the app for debugging.
2. Go to Package explorer, right click on your project and select 'Properties'. In the new dialog you choose 'Java Build Path' and there the register 'Libraries'. In each lib tree is a node called 'Source attachment', that's the one to specify where the source files are.

Answer (score 2):

It means your runtime configuration includes the class in question in a jar file as a library dependency, not as a project dependency.  Since the jar does not contain the source, that is why you get the error.

Not sure what your configuration is or what tools you are using, but simply adding the project to the build path as a dependency will probably resolve your issue.

Comment: Actually main() is some kind of launcher in project A, the class with the breakpoint was in project B, and B depends on A (A is the lower-level library), so I didn't want to add a dependency from A to B. I just had to add B to the source lookup path.