# Cannot import csv file to JAVA

Tags: java, android, eclipse, csv

I met a problem when I was trying to import a csv file into my java code, here is the related java code

```
try {   File file = new File("/home/hanrui/workspace/table.csv");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        reader.readLine();
        String line = null;
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            String item[] = line.split(",");

            String last = item[item.length-1];
            int value = Integer.parseInt(last);
            series1Numbers[row] = value;
            series2Numbers[row] = value;
            row++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and when I debugged it, it reported an error: Source Not Found. But I imported the file like this: File file = new File("/home/hanrui/workspace/table.csv"). (And I debugged other part of my codes with no error reported)

Any help will be appreciated =)

Here is the log:

[2012-06-05 15:27:25 - AndroidPlotExample] Installing AndroidPlotExample.apk...

[2012-06-05 15:27:52 - AndroidPlotExample] Success!

[2012-06-05 15:27:52 - AndroidPlotExample] Starting activity edu.ius.rwisman.AndroidPlotExample.AndroidPlotExampleActivity on device emulator-5554

[2012-06-05 15:27:53 - AndroidPlotExample] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=edu.ius.rwisman.AndroidPlotExample/.AndroidPlotExampleActivity }

[2012-06-05 15:27:54 - AndroidPlotExample] Attempting to connect debugger to 'edu.ius.rwisman.AndroidPlotExample' on port 8643

Comment: Does it literally say "Source Not Found"? *File* not found I've heard of... but not *Source* not found.

Comment: Are you sure the file is in the right location? Do you get any exceptions? If so, please post the stacktrace

Comment: @aioobe Yes it's source not found, and there's a button"Edit Source Lookup Path..."

Comment: @spaniard I'm sure about the location and the absolute path, I'm going to post the stacktrace below

Comment: I don't 'Source Not Found' in log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is probably not related to the code but to some problem with your IDE. By the short error description it looks like the class doesn't have the associated source code.

**Edit:**
Try to close Eclipse and check if there are any java ghost processes. If so kill them, restart Eclipse and try again

Comment: Trying to figure it out if it is the IDE problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is an error with the program or rather how you are running it? "Source Not Found" errors are usually when running Java and it does not know where the source information is for what you're trying to run. This should not be confused with File Not Found which would have thrown an exception. I see nothing really wrong with your code, you create a file pointer, and then make a reader for it and then throw that all in a try/catch clause for IOExceptions which is correct as far as I know.

You should check your setup for running the program. Are you using an IDE? Are you running in command line? Are your files in the proper path?

What happens when you run just a regular print statement in place of the try/catch clause? (Run everything the same way as you have been.)

This might be helpful if you're using Eclipse as an IDE:
[Source not found for a file that I have open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795040/source-not-found-for-a-file-that-i-have-open)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes I'm sure this error is caused by the code I pasted. Cause what I'm trying to do is to learn how to use Androidplot, and its original example runs well; while when I replaced the given array (like Number [] = { 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5} with the code I pasted, the error showed up..

Comment: I'm now trying to see if it is the IDE problem. Thank you again~ =)